# Why doe's my swipeable function always has the same value as my initial value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here is my Code:

```
fun OnTouchTwo() {

        val horizontalSwipeState = SwipeableState("left")
        val horizontalAnchors = mapOf(0f to "left", 1f to "right")

        val verticalSwipeState = SwipeableState("up")
        val verticalAnchors = mapOf(0f to "up", 1f to "down")

        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .swipeable(
                    state = horizontalSwipeState,
                    anchors = horizontalAnchors,
                    orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                    enabled = true,
                    reverseDirection = false,
                    interactionSource = null,
                    thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.7f) },
                    resistance = resistanceConfig(horizontalAnchors.keys),
                    velocityThreshold = Dp(200F)
                )
                .then(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .swipeable(
                            state = verticalSwipeState,
                            anchors = verticalAnchors,
                            orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                            enabled = true,
                            reverseDirection = false,
                            interactionSource = null,
                            thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.7f) },
                            resistance = resistanceConfig(verticalAnchors.keys),
                            velocityThreshold = Dp(200F)
                        )
                )
        ) {
            if(verticalSwipeState.currentValue == "down") {
                println("helloDown")
                Text("Hello i swiped: " +  verticalSwipeState.currentValue)
            } else if(verticalSwipeState.currentValue == "up") {
                println("helloUp")
                Text("Hello i swiped: " + verticalSwipeState.currentValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Somehow my value is alway's "up in this case" whatever i do you eventually know why ?

And swiping doesn't change the text too !

Seems like my initial value is always taken. I put inside the initial functions.

```
val horizontalSwipeState = SwipeableState("left")
val verticalSwipeState = SwipeableState("up")
```

Thanks in advance for your help ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

To create and remember a `SwipeableState` with the default animation, you should use [`rememberSwipeableState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#rememberSwipeableState(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec,kotlin.Function1)):

```
val horizontalSwipeState = rememberSwipeableState("left")
val verticalSwipeState =  rememberSwipeableState("up")

//val horizontalSwipeState = SwipeableState("left")
//val verticalSwipeState = SwipeableState("up")
```